# JS redirect with html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

The question sounds weird, so let me explain. My server sends the client an HTML file as a string (I spent a lot of time trying to use a simple redirect, but couldn't). I want the client to use this html file, but make it seem like a redirect.
In other words, lets say the example.com/blah1 gets the HTML file as a string. I want it to send the user to example.com/blah2, but instead of using blah2.html, use the HTML file from the server. Currently, I have everything figured out but the redirect part. The code below replaces the current DOM with the new one from the server, but the url remains unchanged.

```
        $(".login-form").submit(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var username = $(".username-input").val();
            var password = $(".password-input").val();
            $.post("/loginAttempt",{
                username: username,
                password: password
            },function(data)
            {
                $("html").html(data);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

> The new history entry's URL is given by this parameter. Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance after the user restarts the browser. The new URL does not need to be absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL.

```js
window.history.pushState({
  state: "foo"
}, "title", "/blah2.html");
```